# Error 22 when scanning for available WiFi-Networks using CoreWLAN

Tags: objective-c, macos

I use the following code to scan for all available WiFi-Networks:

```
[[CWInterface interface] scanForNetworksWithSSID:nil error:&err];
```

Usually I get a NSSet of Networks but sometimes I get the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreWLAN.error error
>   22.)
>       Error Domain=com.apple.coreWLAN.error Code=22

I haven't find anything about that error code 22. Is there a documentation or a solution for this?

Comment: is "The operation couldn't be completed" the message that comes out when you output (or log) the string from "`[err localizedDescription]`"?

Comment: Its [err localizedDescription]

Comment: another dumb question, what version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, @Mabstrei (but I will +1 your question to hopefully get more notice from other people). When I look in at [Apple's CWGlobals.h reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWGlobals_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010959), I see a bunch of constants for `CWErr` (and documentation to go with it). If you don't get a good answer, I suggest filing a bug with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com.  CoreWLAN should report back more descriptive errors, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had another problem with CoreWlan(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943833/cwinterface-returning-no-data) i replaced it with Apple80211.framework.

This also is a workaround for this one...