# CWInterface returning no data

Tags: objective-c, macos, corewlan

I try to collect some information about the current state of the CWInterface(connected bssid, available access points...) and send them periodic (every 5-10 sec) via udp to a server.

My Problem is that after some time (between 30 and 50 min in some tests with different collection/sending interval) the CWInterface stops returning data.

- [CWInterface interface] returns nil
- [CWInterface interfaceNames] returns a NSSet with 0 entries
- [[CWInterface interface] scanForNetworksWithSSID:nil &error] also returns a NSSet with 0
  entries

What am I doing wrong?

I'm totaly out of ideas...

Comment: I've run into some issues with that call, it just seems to suck. Throw a bug to apple. I don't know of a work around. Restarting the app seems to work. (I've only used it in iOS, not OSX)

Comment: You use CoreWlan on iOS? How did you do that?
So you think it's a bug in the CoreWlan.framework right?

Comment: Is there any other Api i can call? To get these information without using CoreWlan?

Comment: I changed a few things...
Now i directly call the Apple80211 private framework.
I'm testing it at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK as I already commented my own question I changed the framework from CoreWlan to the private Apple80211.framework.

This seams to work.

My Application now runs for about one and a quater hour and scanning every few seconds.

Two negative points about using Apple80211 are:

- There is no public documentation about how to use it (I used the documentation from http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/ which also works for Mac OS X)
- The scans now last about 5 seconds which is prety long but hey it works...

Comment: Not relevant to you, but you also can't use it in any iOS app that is going to the store :(

Comment: Yeah I know, this one is a port of a app i wrote for iOS... :(