# Can I turn WiFi on and off programmatically and change network? (Mac SDK)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How can I turn WiFi on and off programmatically and change network (WiFi) in the Mac SDK?

Comment: No, haven't found any code yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change most WiFi settings using the [`networksetup(8)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428043154/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) command (see the `-setairportpower` and `-setairportnetwork` options).

As for a programmatic API for adjusting WiFi settings, there is the `CoreWLAN` framework [mentioned by Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910764/596219).

Comment: Do you know, if anything can work on iOS?

Answer (score 8):

[CoreWLAN Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html) seems to fit your needs. There is even a sample code named [CoreWLANWirelessManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html)

> The CoreWLANWirelessManager application utilizes the CoreWLAN
>   framework, which is the Objective-C public API for the Mac OS X IEEE
>   802.11 wireless interface. It gives developers an example of how to use the CoreWLAN API and exercises the functionality that the
>   framework provides.This functionality includes scanning for networks,
>   querying the wireless interface for static and dynamic parameters,
>   toggling interface power, changing channels, association, and
>   accessing the corresponding system configuration preferences for the
>   given interface.

Comment: Do you know, if anything can work on iOS?

Comment: @NikitaP This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943833/cwinterface-returning-no-data  suggests that you can use a private framework to deal with Wlan but I'm not really into networking. It would also prevent your app from being published to the App Store.

Comment: but this wudn't be allowed on App Store, it's using private APIs

Comment: Is the above viable with Mac OS Ventura?